# Weird interaction between setTimeout and state set function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

given this code snippet:

```
const [filled, setFilled] = useState(0);
//...
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("start");
    setFilled(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("old1");
        setFilled(() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("old2");
          }, 1000);
          return 20;
        });
        console.log("old3");
      }, 1000);
      return 10;
    });
  }, []);
```

Can someone explain why old2 is printed twice?
I know the code is weird and stuff, but still, I have no ideas. It has to be something with internal React processing of functional state set function, but I was not able to find any explanation in docs.

Thanks.

Comment: "I have weird code, I do not know what it does, but it does something weird" - Sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: That's just a simplified version of what would be a recursive setTimeout, so it's not that weird.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here with this?

Comment: @ksav, I'm trying to perform certain action - console.log in this case once in a second. The only thing this code is missing - is the recursive setTimeout, with which it doubles the action on each iteration - meaning it would print old2 4, 8, 16 times and so on.

Comment: So you're trying to set state every second? Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and consider editing your question.

Comment: But that is my exact problem :(

Answer (score 1):

Both `setTimeout()` and `setFilled()` are `asynchronously` executing. And we don't have surety about when exactly the outcome is retuned and That's why you have this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You've violated the interface contract that React has provided. The `setState()` updater function must be pure, that is, without side-effects.

The reason this is required is because React makes no guarantees as to when, or how many times the updater function will be invoked.

Even if you think you've determined what the specific behavior is in this case, it may change in the next version without any notice, so don't even try to rely on what you can observe from this "weird" code.